# How to redirect to another URL after fetching data from the server using AJAX?URL redirect not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, redirect

Please take a look at the other post I made. Click here: [How to invoke PHP file in AJAX/JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248352/how-to-invoke-php-file-in-ajax-javascript/17250823#17250823)
I thought everything is working fine until the confirmation box in JavaScript. I have used **window.location** and **window.location.href** but neither of them worked. The confirmation dialogue appears but when the user click the OK button, it just return to the same page. Please help.

Comment: Can you please show us some code?

Comment: Hi, please refer to this post. I answered my question, though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248352/how-to-invoke-php-file-in-ajax-javascript/17250823#17250823

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this  
       redirect = response.getHeader('Location');
                document.location = redirect;
```

Answer (score 0):

location.replace also useful for redirecting the page.
`location.replace('../addmedia.php?add=movies');`